# Synopsis in javascript

Tags: javascript, jslint

By using the  inspect code tool of PHPStorm I get the following message:

```
'recipient_user.id === app.currentUser.id ? true : false' 
 can be simplified to 
'!!(recipient_user.id === app.currentUser.id)'
```

My question is: since the jslint complains about the use of `!!`, is it recommended to change the code according the PHPStorm? or it can be rewrite in a better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would change it to:

```
recipient_user.id === app.currentUser.id
```

Since this is guaranteed to return a genuine boolean value (true or false). There's no need to coerce the return value of the `===` operator using `!!`.